# The limit of the sequence of functions $\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I would like general feedback on my solution to this exercise, as well as a hint for arriving at the solution more directly. I suspect that my approach is sub-optimal.

### Exercise

Does the sequence of functions $ f_n(x) := \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ converge uniformly on $[−1, 1]$? If so, what is the limit function?

### Solution

Yes, it converges uniformly to the function $f(x) = |x|$.

$f_n(x)=f_n(-x)$ and $f(x)=f(-x)$ $\forall n,x$ and so by symmetry, it suffices to consider the limit on $[0,1]$ instead.

We have

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(f_n(x)-f(x)\right) &= 0 \\
 \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}-1 &= 0 \\
 x &= \sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}} \\
 x^2 &= x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align*}

which has no solutions, so $f_n(x)-f(x)$ has no stationary points. Since this is a continuous function on a closed interval, its maximum must be at either $x=0$ or $x=1$.

$$
\|f_n-f\|_\text{sup}=\text{max}\left(\sqrt{0+\frac{1}{n^2}}-0, \sqrt{1^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\right)=\text{max}\left(\frac{1}{n}, \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\right)
$$

Clearly $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and by the algebra of limits $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\to\sqrt{1}-1=0$, so $\|f_n-f\|_\text{sup}\to 0$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly as required.

Comment: The derivative never being zero doesn't mean it has no fixed points, it means it has no local maximum/minimum.

Comment: Otherwise, it is a fine argument.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to write "stationary points" instead. Is that better? This implies that the maximum must be at one of the endpoints.

Comment: You can actually prove $\sqrt{1+1/n^2}<\frac1n$ fairly easily.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like "stationary point," just a person problem. Prefer saying that is no local maximum, so the maximum must be at $0$ or $1.$

Comment: Alternatively. You can see that the derivative is strictly negative (since $x<\sqrt{x^2+1/n^2},$) so the supremum is at $x=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left\lvert \sqrt{x^2 + n^{-2}} - \sqrt{x^2} \right\rvert = \frac{n^{-2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^{-2}} + \sqrt{x^2}} \leq \frac{n^{-2}}{n^{-1}} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
for any $ x \in \mathbf{R}$; it follows that $\sqrt{x^2 + n^{-2}} \to \lvert x \rvert$ uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$ and hence, in particular, on $[-1, 1]$.